# почему программа хочет сделать мой класс абстрактным

Tags: java

Вот код, я хочу понять почему он просит сделать класс "Game" абстрактным, есть идеи? (язык Java если что)

```
package personPackage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public  class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionListener e){

    }

    public frame(){
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        setTitle("Game");
        pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 1500));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pan);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы указали, что ваш класс исполняет интерфейс ActionListener, но не реализовали все функции этого интерфейса.

Comment: ... поэтому нужно или реализовать эти методы, или сделать класс абстрактным, а эти методы реализовать в дочерних классах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для имплементации `ActionListener` класс должен иметь реализацию метода:

```java
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
```

В коде указан неверный тип аргумента `ActionListener` вместо `ActionEvent`, поэтому эта реализация "не засчитана", как относящаяся к указанному интерфейсу.